# When using StreamWriter to save scores via text, it does not show up on the computer when saving

Tags: c#

```
private void btnSaveScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   

 StreamWriter Score;

        if (SaveScores.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Score = File.CreateText("Scoring.txt");
            Score.WriteLine("Your Addition Scores.");
            Score.WriteLine("You scored a " + (AmountCorrect / QuestionsAttempted) + " on the addition calculator!");
            Score.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Saved!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You cancelled the saving process.");
        }
```

I want my program to save the scores and compile what is written in a text file. The issue is that when saving, it does not show the text name, as well as not showing the text filetype. Did I forget to add something?

Comment: Which directory are you looking for it in?

Comment: I want the user to save it to any directory. Im letting the user save the text file. @mnistic

Comment: you specify a file name without a path in the call to `CreateText`. this will default to the current directory. Use a `SaveFileDialog` to ask the user for a location to save, or use one of the special folders like "My Games"

Comment: @dlatikay Im a little confused, can you provide an example? When the code is executed, the Windows menu opens up to let the user save, but like I said it saves nothing to it. No text file, no nothing.

Comment: if no exception is thrown and the "Saved!" message box appears, then there should be a Scoring.txt file somewhere on your computer. try and supply a fixed absolute path like `CreateText(@"c:\Scoring.txt");` to check.

Comment: @dlatikay The files are saved as shortcuts, not text files for some reason. Or it's a "missing shortcut" EDIT: Got it to work! Only issue is that it does not write how many questions the user got correct, etc..

Comment: @dlatikay odd. does not work anymore. It saves at a default space even though I wanted it to save where the user wants, and even then some of the text results dont appear.